# SPO CacheFull and CacheRead

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

In my workflow I create a task and when I go add a user I see in options `_SPOCacheFull` and `_SPOCacheRead`. I wonder what they are for... someone know?

[image]

Comment: While testing with the property `_SPOCacheRead` it didn't send any email to visitors, members nor owners. So my first assumption was terrably wrong. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely something environment specific. 
I would say those are `Portal Super User` and  `Portal Super Reader` accounts as explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656(v=office.14).aspx).

To verify my theory you could run following PoweShell script on the server and compare results:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "<WebApplication>"
$wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"]
$wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"]
```